# How to write structured stream data to Cassandra table using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

**This is my terminal command to run strm.py file**

> $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master local --driver-memory 4g --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 4g --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 org.apache.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0 strm.py

**Error:**

> Cannot load main class from JAR org.apache.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0 with URI org.apache.spark. Please specify a class through --class.
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
>         atorg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:224)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:116)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$1.(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

So can anyone help me out what is the issue with this why it can't loading.

Comment: This is the code i wrote for storing streaming data to Cassandra table .                                   query1 = query.writeStream\
 .option("checkpointLocation", '/tmp/check_point/')\
 .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
 .option("keyspace","test")\
 .option("table", "my_tables")\
 .start()\
 .awaitTermination()

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

- you're incorrectly submitting your application - you don't have a comma between `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0` and `org.apache.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0`, so `spark-submit` treats cassandra connector as a jar, instead of using your python file.
- current version of Spark Cassandra Connector doesn't support direct write for Spark Structured Streaming data - this functionality is available only in DSE Analytics. But you can workaround this by using `foreachBatch`, something like this (not tested, the working Scala code is available [here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingForEachBatch.scala#L59)):

```py
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    df.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("keyspace","test")\
       .option("table", "my_tables").mode('append').save()

query.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

Comment: After writing above function i am getting some error :     pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;

Comment: And also what is epoch_id and what is this used for in def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id): ?

Comment: Regarding node - adjust it to your needs... as error says - you may need to set watermark, but it’s up to your logic. Epoch ID is a number that could be used for some tracking - you can ignore as of now, but it should be in function signature

Comment: I tried this query to store streaming data to Cassandra table:>defwriteToCassandra(writeDF, epochId):writeDF.write\.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\.options(table="my_tables", keyspace="test")\ .mode("append") \.save()
query = df.writeStream \ .trigger(processingTime="10 seconds") \ .outputMode("update") \ .foreachBatch(writeToCassandra) \ .start()\ .awaitTermination()   But i got some errors org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Comment: it looks like that package isn't loaded... before going with the spark streaming job, just check if you can access Cassandra from pyspark at all: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md

Comment: Thanks  @Alex Ott it was helpful.